# ScrollView overflowing to BottomNavigation android

Tags: android, android-fragments, scrollview

[image: Undesired Result]Disclaimer new to android.
Issue: My scrollview is overflowing to navigationbar on bottom.
So i am trying to create an app which uses `BottomNavigationView`. So I created a parent activity which uses `LinearLayout` in `vertically` orientation and has two children. First is `Framelayout` where fragments will reside in. Second is `BottomNavigationView`. Then in fragment I create `ScrollView` and put application UI there. Issue is that fragment application ui takes over (overflows to navigation bar).
Here is my code. What is that I am doing wrong?

This is my activity code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.evildevelopers.answerpoint.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_weight="1">


    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my fragment code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context="com.evildevelopers.answerpoint.StatusFragment"
        android:weightSum="1">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/labelStatus"
            android:layout_width="152dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/fragment_status_label_status"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/previousStatus"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/fragment_status_text_status_hint"
            android:inputType="text|textLongMessage" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switch1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:text="Switch" />

        <DatePicker
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="405dp" />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/timePicker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.56" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:text="@string/fragment_status_btn_save" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

As for code launching the fragment here it's the code.

```
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content , new StatusFragment());
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your framelayout as container like this:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_weight="1">
```

0dp height of the `FrameLayout` will adjust the remaining parent height minus the bottom navbar height. So your scrollview hadn't overflown again.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Relative Layout` do that. In `Frame Layout` your `fragments UI` will goes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />


    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks but it didn't help. Have a look at image if you can to better give you perspective of issue.

Comment: @SachinSharma Are you setting your `Framgent UI` inside `content` or `container` ?

Comment: @SachinSharma Post your updated `activity layout` code above.

Comment: Are you setting your Framgent UI inside content or container ?
Content
.

Comment: @SachinSharma Remove `android:layout_weight="1"` from `Frame Layout` may be it causes that.

Comment: Unfortunately no, still same issue.

Comment: @SachinSharma Try and remove this `android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"`. Try your luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144440/discussion-between-sachin-sharma-and-jaydroider).

Answer (score 0):

Your `BottomNavigationView` looks strange because of the background you are using and the content is cutting off because of your choice of layout.

In the modified code below I have removed your background color on the `BottomNavigationView` and I have made some layout adjustments so that the `FrameLayout` is always rendered above the `BottomNavigationLayout`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/navigation"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also make sure that you remove the `weightSum="1"` set on your `LinearLayout` in the `ScrollView`. I tested the layout above and it should work as is.

**Note:** Only define weights on your layouts when using them to avoid confusion (and possibly, rendering issues). Also seeing that you are new to android I also suggest reading up on [Constraint Layouts](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). This is a handy new layout that will work nicely in your scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately no, this still didnt helped me.